# SQL select records from an arbitrary number of identical tables

Tags: sql, database, dynamic-sql

I am trying to query a database (SQLServer) with multiple tables of identical structure and with related names i.e.

```
[TABLE 01 $TRANSACTIONS]
[TABLE 02 $TRANSACTIONS]
...
[TABLE (n) $TRANSACTIONS]
```

I have a query returning the desired records on one table at a time and can manually select multiple tables with

```
SELECT {QUERY01} FROM [TABLE 01 $TRANSACTIONS]
UNION
SELECT {QUERY02} FROM [TABLE 02 $TRANSACTIONS]
...
SELECT {QUERY(n)} FROM [TABLE (n) $TRANSACTIONS]
```

The generic query into which I substitute the required table name is approx 200 lines, involving a ROWNUMBER()/PARTITION BY function, multiple joins to related tables and some ordering.

Over time, new tables will be added and *n* will change.

Can anyone suggest a way to select the UNION of records from all *n* tables for arbitrary values of *n*?

Note: the list of *n* tables can be easily obtained with a query on the sysobjects table

```
SELECT Name FROM sysobjects
WHERE Type = 'U'
AND Name LIKE '%$TRANSACTIONS'
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Why do you have identical tables with different names? Have you considered normalizing your database? It could make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Just to clarify: I have absolutely no control over the design of this database. It is a (third-party) vendor implementation of one of the Microsoft owned financial systems.

Comment: just because you get the data this way doesn't preclude you creating a normalized option....you would just have to create your own normalized tables and put the data there.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, your best bet is to use your sysobjects query to generate a new view definition periodically.

You might be able to create a DDL trigger which runs the procedure to re-generate this view when your tables change -- I don't really know.  DB designs like this are a trainwreck.

Answer (score 0):

You could cursor through your sysobjects query and construct the sql statement. Then you can call sp_executesql to run it. From experience, I can tell you that these are a pain in the A$$ to debug. I would also expect this solution to fall apart with any vendor upgrade. Good luck.